# AWS kills server upon ssh client auto logout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am running rails application by calling "rails server". I use ssh client to connect to aws. The ssh client connection to aws always auto logout. The message is "Connection reset by 13.250.214.114 port 22". When auto logout, the "rails server" is killed.

Could i stop aws from killing the rails application ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
rails server
```

do:

```
rails s -d
```

then to kill it, find which process is using the port:

```
lsof -i :3000
```

finally, kill the process:

```
kill -9 $(lsof -i :3000 -t)
```

Create aliases:

```
alias startRails='rails server -d'
alias stopRails='kill -9 $(lsof -i :3000 -t)'
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/ahadshafiq/5302058)

Comment: how about this "nohup  rails server & " ?

Comment: when using "rails s -d", i cannot connect to the rails application. The browser prints "This site can't be reached".  Using "lsof -i :3000", the output is:
<pre>COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ruby    4712 ubuntu   10u  IPv4  27891      0t0  TCP localhost:3000 (LISTEN)
ruby    4712 ubuntu   11u  IPv6  27892      0t0  TCP ip6-localhost:3000 (LISTEN)</pre>

Comment: `ruby 4712 ubuntu 10u IPv4 27891 0t0 TCP localhost:3000 (LISTEN)` - why localhost only ?